# Import from outer dir in Python

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a private Python project structured this way:

```
application
├── src
│   └── test_import.py
│   └── __init__.py
|   
└── config
    └── conf.py
    └── __init__.py
```

test_import.py content:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from config import conf
```

When I run `test_import` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

I've seen some packages on GitHub that are using a dot before the file name in order to make the import, something like this:

`from .foo import bar`

This seems to be a more pythonic approach to relative imports in Python (a thing that I'm really new to). And since I don't think that using `sys.append('../')` is a pythonic approach I wanted to know what should I do to my project structure in order to make the """pythonic import""" described above?

Answer (score 0):

you can import your `conf.py` into your `test_import.py` file as

```
# test_import.py file
import sys
from os.path import dirname, join, abspath

sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "..")))

# now you can do
from config import conf

....
```